# Angular js drop down selected is not working with asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am new in angularjs with asp.net mvc,i am facing drop down selection,when i try to selected the drop down its not working.

**Html**

```
 <select class="form-control" required="" name="ProfileID" ng-model="ProfileID">
                                                                    <option value="">--- Select an option ---</option>

                                                                    <option ng-selected= "{{st.ProfileID == ProfileID}}" ng-repeat="st in Profilelist" value="{{st.ProfileID}}">
                                                                        {{st.ProfileName}}
                                                                    </option>>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.ProfileID = responce.data.data[0].ProfileID;//drop down selection
```

**Drop down population**

```
$scope.Profilelist = responce.data.data;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what is the expected result and what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the curly brackets fro the ng-selected so from
ng-selected= "{{st.ProfileID == ProfileID}}"  
to be 
ng-selected= "st.ProfileID == ProfileID"

```
will work on this link http://jsfiddle.net/kn7uzrva/
```